# How to skip image field from retreive if empty [in php]?

Tags: php, html

I am making blog system, which contains: text and image, if user don't insert image, it should skip that image field to retrieve, while it show empty image field in every post. what is wrong with this code? or is there any possible way, if/else conditional statement in echo?

```
$get_posts="SELECT * FROM posts";
$run_posts=mysqli_query($con,$get_posts);
while($row_post=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){

$post_id=$row_post['post_id'];
$user_id=$row_post['user_id'];      
$post_img=$row_post['post_image'];  
$post_cnt=$row_post['post_cnt'];
$post_date=$row_post['post_date'];      

echo"<div class='posts'>
<p>$post_date</p>   
<p><img src='img/$post_img'width='380'height='auto'/></p>
<p>$post_cnt</p>
<a href='single.php?post_id=$post_id'style='float:right;'>
<button>See Replies or Reply to This</button></a>
</div><br/>";
```

}

Comment: Can you explain further why you ask about problems in that code? Is there something that is not working? Any error message?

Comment: @Nico Haase:  there is no error message, but blank space visible in every user's post, who did not upload it, check it what i mean: https://ibb.co/QrYXK1S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use if else condition :

```
$get_posts="SELECT * FROM posts";
$run_posts=mysqli_query($con,$get_posts);
while($row_post=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){

    $post_id=$row_post['post_id'];
    $user_id=$row_post['user_id'];      
    $post_img=$row_post['post_image'];  
    $post_cnt=$row_post['post_cnt'];
    $post_date=$row_post['post_date'];      



    $output = '<div class="posts"><p>'.$post_date.'</p>';

    if($post_img != ''){
        $output .= '<p><img src="img/'.$post_img.'" width="380" height="auto"/></p>';
    }

    $output .= '<p>'.$post_date.'</p><p>'.$post_cnt.'</p>
    <a href="single.php?post_id='.$post_id.' "style="float:right;">
        <button>See Replies or Reply to This</button></a>
    </div><br/>';

    echo $output; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create image tag if `$post_img` has some value

```
if(!empty($post_img)){
echo"<div class='posts'>
    <p>$post_date</p>   
    <p><img src='img/$post_img'width='380'height='auto'/></p>
    <p>$post_cnt</p>
    <a href='single.php?post_id=$post_id'style='float:right;'>
    <button>See Replies or Reply to This</button></a>
    </div><br/>";   
}
```

Comment: it show only single post, while all user's recent post disappeared

Comment: so just want to hide image or this whole div?

Answer (score 0):

Store full path of image in an variable.

```
$assets_url = '';// Define full path of your assets. <br>
// Like http://localhost/Project/img/
$post_img_url = $assets_url.$post_img;
```

Checking post_image column value is not empty will not work in few cases where some value exits in column but image does not exits in directory.
So use getimagesize() function to check dimensions of image, if it does not return false then show image.

```
if(getimagesize($post_img_url) != FALSE){

  echo '<p><img src="'.$post_img_url.'" width="380" height="auto"/></p>';

}
```

This will not show image tag (black space) in case there is no image uploaded.